# How to save data file into .RData?

Tags: r, rdata

I want to save data into an `.RData` file.

For instance, I'd like to save into `1.RData` with two csv files and some information.

Here, **I have two csv files**

```
1) file_1.csv contains object city[[1]]
2) file_2.csv contains object city[[2]]
```

and additionally save other values, country and population as follows.
So, I guess I need to make objects 'city' from two csv files first of all.

The structure of 1.RData may looks like this:

```
> data = load("1.RData")

> data
[1] "city"  "country"  "population"

> city
  [[1]]               
  NEW YORK         1.1
  SAN FRANCISCO    3.1

  [[2]]
  TEXAS            1.3
  SEATTLE          1.4

> class(city)
  [1] "list"

> country
  [1] "east"  "west"  "north"

> class(country)
  [1] "character"

> population
  [1] 10  11  13  14   

> class(population)
  [1] "integer"
```

`file_1.csv` and `file_2.csv` have bunch of rows and columns.

How can I create this type of RData with csv files and values?

Answer (score 101):

Alternatively, when you want to save individual R objects, I recommend using `saveRDS`.

You can save R objects using `saveRDS`, then load them into R with a new variable name using `readRDS`.

Example:

```
# Save the city object
saveRDS(city, "city.rds")

# ...

# Load the city object as city
city <- readRDS("city.rds")

# Or with a different name
city2 <- readRDS("city.rds")
```

But when you want to save many/all your objects in your workspace, use Manetheran's answer.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of `saveRDS` even though it's also base R... I have always been using Manetheran's solution.

Comment: I don’t know why this isn’t more widely recommended / known. It’s usually a much better solution than `save` / `load`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why is `saveRDS` better? With `save/load` you use `save(object, file)` and `newObject <- load(file)`. With RDS you use `saveRDS(object, file)` and  `newObject <- readRDS(file)`. They seem similar to me, but for the few extra keystrokes using `saveRDS` and `readRDS`. I assume I am missing something.

Comment: @jabberwocky `load` by default dumps objects into your (global) environment. That’s a terrible idea. You *want* the control that `readRDS` gives you. R’s `load` is actively promoting bad practice here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Again, I assume I'm missing something. I don't see `load` clearing the environment. I created an SSCC example. The code is awkward in the comment here, but here it goes: `test <- cbind(1:10, 11:20); save(test, file = "example.Rdata");  remove(list = ls());  load("example.Rdata");  test1 <- 1:10;  test2 <- 11:20;  ls();  ls(envir=.GlobalEnv);  load("example.Rdata");  ls();  ls(envir=.GlobalEnv);  #Load does not remove objects from environment. ie test1 and test2 are still there`.

Comment: @jabberwocky Think about this scenario: say you save your matrix, `test` with `save(test, file = "example.Rdata")`. Then you later define `test` as something else (say, `test <- c(1:100)`). What happens when you do `load("example.Rdata")`? It will replace your newly defined `test` variable. Another scenario: what if you need the data that you saved in `example.rdata`, but want to keep the newly defined `test` variable. Can you *easily* load `example.Rdata` into a new variable, say `test3` with `load`?

Comment: The utility that I find in `save` is to save my current environment in R, but to save individual R objects, I find `saveRDS` and `readRDS` are much better.

Answer (score 95):

There are three ways to save objects from your R session:

#### Saving all objects in your R session:

The [`save.image()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) function will save all objects currently in your R session:

```
save.image(file="1.RData")
```

These objects can then be loaded back into a new R session using the [`load()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html) function:

```
load(file="1.RData")
```

#### Saving some objects in your R session:

If you want to save some, but not all objects, you can use the [`save()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) function:

```
save(city, country, file="1.RData")
```

Again, these can be reloaded into another R session using the [`load()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html) function:

```
load(file="1.RData")
```

#### Saving a single object

If you want to save a single object you can use the [`saveRDS()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) function:

```
saveRDS(city, file="city.rds")
saveRDS(country, file="country.rds")
```

You can load these into your R session using the [`readRDS()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) function, but you will need to assign the result into a the desired variable:

```
city <- readRDS("city.rds")
country <- readRDS("country.rds")
```

But this also means you can give these objects new variable names if needed (i.e. if those variables already exist in your new R session but contain different objects):

```
city_list <- readRDS("city.rds")
country_vector <- readRDS("country.rds")
```

Comment: This is a nice answer.  An extra line with the corresponding `load()` instruction would make it better IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an additional function should you need it. You can include a variable in the named location, for example a date identifier

```
date <- yyyymmdd
save(city, file=paste0("c:\\myuser\\somelocation\\",date,"_RData.Data")
```

This was you can always keep a check of when it was run