# Error when unlisting columns in a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame called DF:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

letters <- list("A", "B", "C", "D")
numbers <- list(list(1,2), 1, 1, 2)
score <- list(.44, .54, .21, .102)

DF <- data.frame(cbind(letters, numbers, score))
```

Note that all columns in the data frame are of class "list".

Also, take a look at the structure: DF$numbers[1] is also a list

I'm trying to UNLIST each column.

```
 DF$letters <- unlist(DF$letters)
 DF$score <- unlist(DF$score)
 DF$numbers <- unlist(DF$numbers)
```

However, because, DF$numbers[1] is also a list, I'm thrown back this error:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, numbers, value = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2)) : 
   replacement has 5 rows, data has 4
```

Is there a way that I can unlist the whole column, and keep the values cells like DF$numbers[1] as a character vector like c(1,2) or 1,2?

Ideally I would like DF to look something like this, where the individual values in the **number column are still of type int:**

```
 letters   numbers   score
  A         1,2       .44
  B         1         .54
  C         1         .21
  D         2         .102
```

The goal is to then write the data frame to a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `unlist` to each individual element of the column *numbers* instead of the whole column:

```
DF$numbers <- lapply(DF$numbers, unlist)

DF
#  letters numbers value
#1       A    1, 2 0.440
#2       B       1 0.540
#3       C       1 0.210
#4       D       2 0.102

DF$numbers[1]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
```

Or paste the elements as a single string if you want an atomic vector column:

```
DF$numbers <- sapply(DF$numbers, toString)
DF
#  letters numbers value
#1       A    1, 2  0.44
#2       B       1  0.54
#3       C       1  0.21
#4       D       2 0.102

DF$numbers[1]
#[1] "1, 2"

class(DF$numbers)
# [1] "character"
```

Comment: Hi!  That's a great tip, however DF$numbers is still in list format.  When I try and unlist() that DF$numbers <- unlist(lapply(DF$numbers,unlist)), I'm thrown back the same error i described in my original post

Comment: The *numbers* column will be list if the elements contain vector like `c(1,2)`. If don't want it to be a list, you can paste the elements as a string as `DF$numbers <- sapply(DF$numbers, toString)`.

Comment: I see, Yes, I would like the elements of the list to be of type int.  Using your initial approach with lapply, when I try to write DF using write.csv I'm thrown back an error " Error in write.table(DF, "test.csv", col.names = NA, sep = ",", dec = ".",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'"

Comment: If your purpose is to write the data frame to csv file, then it makes sense to convert the column to character columns before hand. Did you try the second approach?

Comment: Yes, however I would like the numbers to still be of type int

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In a csv file, all the numbers are strings. Maybe `DF$numbers <- sapply(DF$numbers, function(x) paste0(as.integer(unlist(x)), collapse = ","))`?

Comment: You can save *dataframe* as objects, if you want to keep the data type information. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967478/how-to-save-data-file-into-rdata)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
DF$letters <- unlist(DF$letters)
DF$value <- unlist(DF$value)
DF$numbers <- unlist(as.character(DF$numbers))
```

This returns:

```
DF
  letters numbers value
1       A c(1, 2) 0.440
2       B       1 0.540
3       C       1 0.210
4       D       2 0.102
```